# What could be causing the strange behavior of flickity slider on mobile devices and how can I resolve it?

Tags: javascript, slider, flickity

I am using flickity slider but its behaving strangely in mobiles. its looking fine in chrome inspect mobile views.
[chrome inspect s20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMySz.png)

In s20 original phone -  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyKPy.jpg)

Is it because of loading speed of images as flickity slider decides viewport size based on the components ( images inside.. Should I add lazy loading?

I tried adding exact width and size, lazy loading to some